# JQuery open a link with specific ul on top

Tags: php, jquery, href

I have a menu like below. Have a look.
Let's say that this menu is on "page.php".
What i want to achieve is that when I click a link on index.php with href="page.php#tab2" it opens page.php with #tab2 displayed instead of #tab1.
Hope You can help me.

```js
    $("#tab2").hide();
    $("#tab3").hide();

$("#tab1_click").click(function () {
        $("#tab2, #tab3").hide("blind");
        $("#tab1").delay(200).show("blind");
    });

$("#tab2_click").click(function () {
        $("#tab1, #tab3").hide("blind");
        $("#tab2").delay(200).show("blind");
    });

$("#tab3_click").click(function () {
        $("#tab2, #tab1").hide("blind");
        $("#tab3").delay(200).show("blind");
    });
```

```css
ul {margin:0;}
#nav li {display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}
#tab1_click {background:#ccc;}
#tab2_click {background:#ddd;}
#tab3_click {background:#eee;}
#tab1 {width: 300px; height:300px; background:#ccc}
#tab2 {width: 300px; height:300px; background:#ddd}
#tab3 {width: 300px; height:300px; background:#eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav"><li id="tab1_click">Tab 1</li><li id="tab2_click">Tab 2</li><li id="tab3_click">Tab 3</li></ul>
<ul id="tab1">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>

<ul id="tab2">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>

<ul id="tab3">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: use `location.hash` to match to your tabs when page loads

Comment: i see that with page.php#tab2   location.hash   will return #tab2 but now, how to compare this using if / else and 'var x = location.hash' with the div id to run $("#tab2").show();

Comment: look what this would do `$(location.hash).show()` ... hash and your selector are identical. Just make sure it's not undefined before you put it in `$()`